# How to call (Invoke) dart method from swift native code (AppDelegate)??The "invokeMethod" is working on android but not in ios

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter

> I'm trying to call function("onRazorPayPaymentFail" method) in dart
>   file (main.dart) from AppDelegate class of ios using invokeMethod of
>   flutter channel.But it is not working.The method onRazorPayPaymentFail
>   is firing on Android.But In iOS it is not working.

**//main.dart from lib folder**

```
//main.dart from lib folder
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  static const razorpay_platform =
      const MethodChannel('com.algorin.pf.razorpay');

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    razorpay_platform.setMethodCallHandler(myUtilsHandler);
  }

  Future<dynamic> myUtilsHandler(MethodCall methodCall) async {
    switch (methodCall.method) {
      case 'onRazorPayPaymentFail':
        print(json.decode(methodCall.arguments));
        break;
      case 'onRazorPayPaymentSuccess':
        processSuccessResponse(json.decode(methodCall.arguments));
        break;
      default:
    }
  }
//..................................
}}
```

And  AppDelegate.Swift  file

```
//AppDelegate.Swift  file
import UIKit 
import Flutter 
import Razorpay 
@UIApplicationMain 
@objc class AppDelegate : FlutterAppDelegate,
RazorpayPaymentCompletionProtocol {
    //..............
    var controller : FlutterViewController!;
    var RAZORPAY_IO_CHANNEL : FlutterMethodChannel!;

    override func application (
        _ application : UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions : [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?)->
Bool {
    controller = window?.rootViewController as? FlutterViewController;
    RAZORPAY_IO_CHANNEL = FlutterMethodChannel (
        name : "com.algorin.pf.razorpay",
        binaryMessenger : controller
    )
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register (with: self);
    return super.application (
        application,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions : launchOptions
    );
}

public func onPaymentError (_ code: Int32, description str: String)
{
    print (
        "<<<<<<<<<<< Payment Failed >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"
    );
    RAZORPAY_IO_CHANNEL.invokeMethod ("onRazorPayPaymentFail", arguments: str);
}
//............
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a solution? - I'm facing same issue

Comment: actually, I've just tried with updated version of Flutter and it's working fine - you probably figured that out ages ago !

Comment: @JonCook, what were your previous and new versions of Flutter?

Comment: sorry, not sure what old version was - new version is: $ flutter --version
Flutter 1.9.1+hotfix.6 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 68587a0916 (9 weeks ago) • 2019-09-13 19:46:58 -0700
Engine • revision b863200c37
Tools • Dart 2.5.0
[john@MacBook-Pro metronom